# NGINX upstream based on $scheme

Tags: proxy, nginx, ssl

We have an upstream which can serve both HTTP and HTTPS traffic. 
The question is - how to make NGINX send traffic to the correct upstream's port?

Current config is:

```
upstream  platfrom-dev-eu-app {
    server 52.***.***.80:443;
}
...
server {
...

    location / {
        proxy_redirect          off;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass $scheme://platfrom-dev-eu-app$request_uri;
    }
}
```

The only solution I see here - is to add two upstreams, one with *:80* and second with *:443*, and then use if/else in the `server {}` to chose correct one (or just set port after `proxy_pass`), like:

```
upstream  platfrom-dev-eu-app-ssl {
    server 52.***.***.80:443;
}

upstream  platfrom-dev-eu-app {
    server 52.***.***.80;
}
...
    if ($scheme = "http") {
         proxy_pass http://platfrom-dev-eu-app$request_uri;
    }

    if ($scheme = "https") {
        proxy_pass https://platfrom-dev-eu-app-ssl$request_uri;
    }
```

Is it right solution here - or there is more suitable approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the if statement by simply declaring two servers, this is a pattern I use for this kind of thing:

```
upstream  platfrom-dev-eu-app-ssl {
    server 52.***.***.80:443;
}

upstream  platfrom-dev-eu-app {
    server 52.***.***.80;
}

server {
  listen 80;

  include "common.conf";
  proxy_pass http://platfrom-dev-eu-app$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  # SSL configuration

  include "common.conf";
  proxy_pass https://platfrom-dev-eu-app-ssl$request_uri;
}
```

Create the `common.conf` file and put your common configuration to both servers in it.

Really though, if you are on a trusted and secure network you could just terminate SSL on the reverse proxy and just talk plain text to your application servers. Afterwards on the application server define a server on a port that is for SSL connections and set the fastcgi param `HTTPS` to `on`.